# App to App messaging using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, messaging

I am building an app-to-app messaging appplication using firebase. When I am trying to run the app, it shows me following the error:
[image]

what is the problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: can you share you build.gradle file (the one in the folder app)

Comment: Don't post screenshots of text please. Instead capture the actual text and add it to your question by clicking the little edit link under it. Also be sure to share the [minimal code (and JSON, and gradle) that are needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It worked when i have added                                                                               packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }    in build.gradle